# How do you build your own RFID reader?

Tags: rfid, antenna

What's involved in building your own RFID reader? As you guys would know industrial RFID readers aren't cheap, how do you energise the antenna, then read back the output?

Comment: If you are looking for something cheap [this](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/125khz-rfid-module-uart-p-171.html?zenid=09bfb99d14c91f240ff5e9077a3d0d0e) may do the trick.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a University(UG) level final project detailing one [here.](http://instruct1.cit.cornell.edu/courses/ee476/FinalProjects/s2006/cjr37/Website/index.htm)

There's a more general RFID eavesdropper/reader [here.](http://cq.cx/proxmark3.pl)

Answer (score 7):

before beginning, you have to know that there are mainly two type of RFID Reader:

1. 125 khz : antenna of 100 turn coil
2. 13.6 Mhz : antenna of 3-5 turn coil, more sofisticated can include communication protocol and security issues

if it just to open a door or something like that you can use the 125 khz

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit old, but in case someone else is reading in 2012.  Actually there are then three "types".. Another common one is 134.2 kHz

Quoted from above answers:
....before beginning, you have to know that there are mainly two type of RFID Reader:

125 khz : antenna of 100 turn coil
13.6 Mhz : antenna of 3-5 turn coil, more sofisticated can include communication protocol and security issues.....

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

SparkFun has a lot of [parts and boards](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/advanced%5Fsearch%5Fresult.php?keywords=rfid&x=0&y=0&search%5Fsection=products) that can help you as well.